# can't access a mongoose schema's method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a new method inside of my mongoose schema and use it in my API functions.
For some reason, I can't access the function, and it keeps to show me an error that the requested function is not a function.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const chillersSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      dateTime: {
        type: Date
      },
      enteringWaterTemp: {
        type: Number
      },
      leavingWaterTemp: {
        type: Number
      },
      enteringGasTemp: {
        type: Number
      },
      leavingGasTemp: {
        type: Number
      },
      firstCircuitPressure: {
        type: Number
      },
      secondCiruitPressure: {
        type: Number
      },
      controlPoint: {
        type: Number
      },
      unitPrecentActiveCapacity: {
        type: Number
      },
      demandLimit: {
        type: Number
      },
      chillerState: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
  },
  { versionKey: false}
);

chillersSchema.methods.convertData = function(originalData) {
    return 0;
}

const Chiller1 = mongoose.model('Chiller1', chillersSchema, 'chiller1');
const Chiller2 = mongoose.model('Chiller2', chillersSchema, 'chiller2');
const Chiller3 = mongoose.model('Chiller3', chillersSchema, 'chiller3');

module.exports = { Chiller1, Chiller2, Chiller3 };
```

I can make Chiller1/2/3 objects on my API but I can't use this function for some reason.
Any ideas?